# stack panel of toggle buttons where one at most is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There is more than one button checked at a time.

3D and Text are checked

[image]

Comment: That is correct. Good observation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is the buttons to be mutually exclusive, I suggest you edit your question to make that clear.

You could style radiobuttons as togglebuttons because radiobuttons have this behaviour built in.

Here's a proof of concept to show you the idea.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
      TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>        
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton>A</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>B</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>C</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The styling is of course completely different to what you have.
Click a button and it becomes checked, you see the letter appear red. Click another one and that becomes checked and the previous one unchecked.

This should at least get you started.

If it doesn't do exactly what you want and you need finer control of logic then you could instead template an itemscontrol into your buttons and then use some linq to iterate the bound collection and apply your logic. Whatever that is.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_